# Lotus Notes email as an attachment to another email

Tags: email, attachment, lotus-notes

This is in Notes 8.5 environment.

I just wanted to know how to attach an email to another email as *real* attachment not a "Document Link".

I intended to attach an email, so I drag & dropped an email to another email's body but this turned out to be a "Document Link". This is an issue when I deleted the original attachment(an email in this case) and want to open the attachment again.

Tried to drag & drop the email to desktop and attach that through the "Choose file" dialog, didn't work either.

So how can I do that? I'm trying to get the attachment programmatically.

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically or manually? Is the mail recipient also using a Notes client?

Answer (score 8):

The only way I know is this:

Reassure that preferences | Basic Notes Client configuration | Drag and drop saves as eml file is checked

1) Drag your email to e.g. your desktop  or to an explorer instance (will be saved as an eml file).
2) Attach this file to your opened email by either selecting it with the paperclip menu item or drag 'n drop the file into the opened email.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open msg
2. Save to desktop
3. Open new mail
4. Attached *.eml file on desktop

Sad to say, this is the only way I know which sux because in Outlook, you just need to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

> Answer from Chris is not possible
>   because there is no save mail option
>   (at least in version 8.5) in LN

It is possible, File > Save As

Answer (score 1):

answer from Alexey creates MS Outlook eml files, so if you don't have Outlook e-mail client doesn't help.
Answer from Chris is not possible because there is no save mail option (at least in version 8.5) in LN.
So one of the possible solutions would be to hold control, select all mails you want to attach, right click on the selected mails, from the menu select Forward and it will open the new message with all selected mails in the body of the new message.

Answer (score 1):

You can slecet sent item /email and drag to desktop , it will automatic created new file on desktop. Then you can attach and send it in to new emails.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently encountered the same issue and hopefully what follows will be helpful.
In Windows, the default program for opening .eml files is set to Outlook. Every user of Lotus notes should take the steps to have .eml files defaulted to open via Lotus notes.

Start menu--- Defaults programs---Lotus notes-- and check .eml--- then save.

After performing this, Lotus notes will be the default to open these attachments.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to do this for a while also.
Here is what I do now.
Highlight the email you want to create as a file.
Click on Create. Hover over Special, then click on Link message.
This will open up a new tab for the link.
At the bottom of the message is a small yellow piece of paper icon.
Copy this icon and paste into your message like you would any other file.
It is tiny, so I put a statement like "see email attachment ---->" in front of the icon.
You might like this way. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Tested vith Notes versions 6.5.x and 7.0.x
From your Lotus Notes inbox

1. Open the message
2. Click View > Show > Page Source
3. Copy all the data into a text file and save the file with .eml extension.
4. Create a new message
5. Attach the .eml file(s) and send the new message

Hop this helps. I have no client on my current machine but will test from home on 8.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Copy the mail as a document link (right click on the mail and you should get this option) and paste it in the new mail. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Talking about IBM Notes v. 9 is pretty easy.

To choose the e-mail to be attached and drag until the new e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Click on email which you want to forward

Edit - > Copy As -> Document Link

create new mail and paste.

it will work

Comment: `So how can I do that? I'm trying to get the attachment programmatically.`  This isn't programatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lotus Notes V9.X, it is better to drag the mail to desktop as .eml and then attach it to the mail. Safest way so far.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not exactly what your looking for and you probably don't care at this point since the question was asked 5 years ago, one method is to use "forward".

Go to your inbox or wherever your messages are and select the 2+ messages you want to send than simply click forward... all messages get combined into 1.

Answer (score -1):

I might be very late but encoutered this problem sometime before and saw this link.
Thanks . Please check this shall work.

Goto Create menu -> Section--> Copy email to be inserted